# How do I increase the image size upload limit in Magento?

Tags: images, magento, uploading, file-size

Is there a way to increase the maximum image upload file size from 2mb to 5 or 10mb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Someone on the Magento forums posted the following as their solution:](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/124630/)

> You have to change both `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in the `php.ini`
>
> And don’t forget to restart your server afterwards.

Comment: Everyone following @onmouse answer and you cannot make why this is happening, you might need to run also `service php5-fpm reload`